# EE3 MSM - What can it handle?

Tags: multi-site-manager, ee3

I'm looking into potential solutions for an upcoming project which requires a platform that can utilise 1 CMS to mantain many websites.

I don't have any prior experience with MSM so I'm not overly sure what it can handle, so any advice would be greatly appreciated please.

I realise the sites would all need to reside on one server which is fine, however how many sites could it run? This project would potentially have many hundreds of sites under one MSM install?

Also, I'm fairly sure each site can have it's own templates/styles etc but just wanted to double check?

What would happen with regards to upgrading the main install, would it update across the board I assume?

One more question, is it still a case of buying a license for each new site within MSM?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have only done a MSM install with 30 sites. Currently building one with potentially 50-100 sites.  It uses the main EE install for all of the site's codebase. So updating EE, updates all.  I have not done this with EE3 yet.